# Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char' for spa

Tags: haskell

I am trying to give the names of spa a given supervisor that rated the skill service along with their rating result for each spa. But I keep getting this error shown below. Sorry if my code look horrible since I am new to Haskell.

```
* Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char'
  Expected type: Spa -> Service
    Actual type: Spa -> [Service]
* In the second argument of `(.)', namely `getService'
  In the first argument of `filter', namely `((== se) . getService)'
  In the expression: filter ((== se) . getService)
```

I tried by retrieving and filtering for the supervisor. Then I output it all. Is it possible to just output name of supervisor, spa and level rating? Am I going the right track? How to fix the error?

```
data Spa = Spa SID Brand Area Stars [(Service, LevelRating)]

-- spa service
getService :: Spa -> [Service]
getService (Spa _ _ _ _ xs) = map fst xs

-- filter spa service
spaService :: Service -> [Spa] -> [Spa]
spaService se = filter ((==se) . getService)

ratedListStr :: Spa -> String
ratedListStr (Spa sid br ar st s) = "\nSpaID: " ++ sid ++ "\n Brand: " ++ br ++ "\n Area: " ++ ar ++ "\n Star: " ++ show st ++ "\n Service Rating" ++ show s
```

Comment: `getService` returns a *list* of `Service`s, zo `[Service]`, wheras `se` is a single `Service`, so `(==se)` does not make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getService` returns a *list* of `Service`s, zo `[Service]`, wheras `se` is a single `Service`, so `(==se)` does not make much sense. Since of of the operands is a `Service` and the other one is a `[Service]`. Since [**`(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-61--61-) acts on two items of the same type, this does not typecheck.

If you want to check if the `se` is for example an element of the services, you can make use of [**`elem :: Foldable f => a -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem):

```
spaService :: Service -> [Spa] -> [Spa]
spaService se = filter (elem se . getService)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Wilem! The error has disappear but when i type in terminal ratedListStr "Colin" [(Spa "03" "John" "Orchard" 6 [("Colin", 9), ("Susan", 3)])],  it says Variable not in scope: ratedListedStr :: [Char] -> [Spa] -> t. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Nami: it is `ratedListStr`, not `ratedListedStr` (notice the `ed` after `List`).

Comment: I try ratedListStr "Colin" [(Restaurant "03" "John" "Orchard" 6 [("Colin", 9), ("Susan", 3)])]  but it still show the same error though

Comment: @Nami: but the error shows `Variable not in scope: ratedListedStr :: [Char] -> [Spa] -> t`, so it means you somehow call a function `ratedListedStr`.

Comment: Sorry i mean this variable not in scope error ratedListStr :: [Char] -> [Restaurant] -> t

Comment: @Nami: but you pass a list of `Restaurant`s, not `Spa`s.